# What is the difference between [src] and bind-src in Property Binding

Tags: angular

I am able to find difference between the interpolation and the other syntax type of property binding but not between below two

1. [src]
2. bind-src

if both are doing the same then why two different syntax
  for eg. when we have only string value at that time we can use {{bannerimg}} in angular

```
  <img src="{{ bannerimg }}">
```

trying to find out difference between below two and

```
  <img [src]="bannerimg">
  <img bind-src="bannerimg">
```

Answer (score 2):

There is not much of a difference when you are using something like this

```
<img [src]="bannerimg">
  <img bind-src="bannerimg">
```

But, When you are using `<img src="{{ bannerimg }}">` the value of src is dynamic so which will help you in rendering the dynamically loaded image.

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference between the two. Square brackets `[*]` are added as a syntactic sugar over `bind-*` and round brackets `(*)` translate to `on-*` canonical form. Finally, using 'banana-in-a-box' syntax `[(*)]` translates to `bindon-*`.
Source: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-target

Answer (score 0):

Main difference is if you care about W3C validation. They tend to dislike the brackets, and for that you can use the alternative `bind-` syntax